Ubuntu Server: TAP devices fail to activate with `ip link set dev up`
OS: Ubuntu Server 24.04.1 LTS; Kernel: 6.8.0-48-generic
I'm able to create TAP devices using ip tuntap, but I can't seem to bring them up. For example:
root@openstack-ctrl:/# ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap
root@openstack-ctrl:/# ip link set dev tap0 up

I do not receive any errors running these commands (e.g., RTNETLINK). When I check the links with ip l, I'll see something like this:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master ovs-system state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:ff:bf:01:9a:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp1s0
14: ovs-system: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6a:f8:c1:2d:08:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
15: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:ff:bf:01:9a:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
21: tap0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ae:55:f2:d1:11:b4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

All further attempts to bring up tap0 silently fail. Note that I'm running Open vSwitch (OVS). Afaik it's not relevant, but I'm leaving it in just in case I'm wrong about that.
When I check the dmesg logs for anything specific to the tap devices, the only thing I see are messages about the tap device entering and exiting promiscuous mode. I've tried attaching to the ovs bridge (br0) as a port to see if I could get a little more detail in the openvswitch-switch logs, but no dice. Recreating the TAP device yields the same result.
I've also checked for the tun module. According to modinfo, it's built in, and filtering the dmesg logs for tun does return this:
[    0.412870] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6

So it's clearly loading and /dev/net/tun is present, so it should be functional. Whatever is going on is apparently unrelated to initialization.
Edit: For the sake of argument I've also tried activating TAP devices with the network manager (netplan) disabled.
I have a little experience with virtual networking, but this beats me. I'm obviously missing something here. What else can I check to try to diagnose the problem?
